# how git-slab and slack URL is working?

Tags: git, nginx, gitlab, slack

I want work like slack and git-lab are doing in my project. More description in given below.

How **`www.abc.com`** can **`www.cop.abc.com`** can be done by code with help of Nginx

FOR EXAMPLE - As SLACK / GIT-LAB is working like IF i make new organization in 
**`www.slack.com`** then URL sets to **`www.myOrgName.slack.com`** , same like this git-lab is working.

Can anyone specify how its working?